# Redirecting on a single search result?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

When a user does a search on my website, and there is only one entry, then I want to redirect the user to the search result. The current way that I am doing this is poor. Here is how I am currently doing this:

If there is only one search result on the search result page, then I render a hidden input with an ID of "redirect" and a value of the link to redirect to. In the javascript, if the hidden input with ID "redirect" exists, then the user is redirected to the value of the element.

It's a poor way to do this because the single search result is loaded first, so the user actually sees that there is one search result. Then, it loads after, say, 3 seconds.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: We need some extra info for this. What kind of CMS software are you using? Can you read/write PHP? Because that would be the best place to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the header() PHP function to redirect if there is only 1 result.

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

Comment: Just something to note, use the [full site location](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) when using the `Location:` header.

Answer (score 1):

You should use PHP to determine if there is only one result, then do a server-side redirect like so:

```
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/redirect_page.html' );
exit;
```

Before printing anything to the page, check to see if there is only one result, and if so, render that script and exit so that nothing else gets processed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
//Query & other stuff

$num_of_results=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_of_results==0){
    //no results

}elseif($num_of_results==1){
    //only 1 result
    //pseudo-code
    //get id or controller ect from result set
    header('Location: ./page/'.$id);
    die();
}else{
    //normal display of search results
    while($row=.......){

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your logic is that you're waiting for something in the page to load THEN redirecting. I think a more elegant solution is to change the flow of things to give you a little more flexibility.

First, you're going to want to preprocess your query and check for the pertinent information; if there is one result, use the `header();` redirects as mentioned. You may need to add some more information to the result set (database table) to make this possible.

I think taking this a step further, however, would be to redirect certain terms automatically as well. You'll kill two birds with one stone.

Let's say you have a database that is `term` and `url` - you could add certain terms to the list that also serve as a redirect. This is great for certain keywords that there are variations of. Use this sparingly though - it is great to use in conjunction with your site statistics. It may help you in instances where 0 records are shown.